# Writing a modular program

Tags: c#, oop, modular-design

I want to make my program "modular" and I'm wondering if I'm taking the right approach to this.

What I mean by this is I want to have some reusable "processing" stuff contained within it's own c# files. In this way, I could simply copy the files between projects to be able to reuse my code. Since this probably doesn't make sense, let me explain with an example.

**Program.cs**

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] x = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        BClass b = new BClass(x);
        Console.Write("[ ");
        foreach (int i in x)
        {
            Console.Write(i + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("]\n");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**BClass.cs**

```
class BClass
{
    int[] x;
    public BClass(int[] x)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            x[i] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this works fine, I get the output I would expect, but it feels *wrong*, I guess? In addition to my gut feeling, I am getting warnings (as I would expect) because the `BClass` object is unused. Ultimately, my question is **What is the best way to make a program modular like this?** Using a class feels wrong because I end up with a reference to an object that will never be used. Perhaps I'm using the class wrong?

Comment: 1-Subjective questions like this will be surely closed on S.O. 2-Creating a class is a good idea, but instead of doing things in the constructor, then just create static functions and use them, you don't need a BClass instance at all. 3-If you really want to reuse code then put those classes in a class library, better than copying files between projects.

Comment: how about explaining what you are trying to accomplish without posting all the `python` code which isn't relevant in regards to C# if you do not understand Classes and how they work as well as event driven program in regards to C# perhaps you should do some more reading up to understand the differences between how things are done in .net vs python.. modular or not..

Comment: @Gusman I didn't think this was very subjective, I've edited the title to clarify. In my program the processing is done in static methods rather than the constructor, this was a simple example, however I do need to pass in values and as such I've used the constructor.

Comment: It's subjective because there are tons of ways to do that and every programmer will prefer one above other, but all of these ways will be correct. And you don't need a constructor to pass a parameter to a function, per example you can declare in your example `public static void ProcessArray(int[] x)` and then call it `BClass.ProcessArray(x);`

Comment: I wasn't aware of this; I just tested this with my simple script and I see how I can refactor my actual application using this method. Thanks for the information.

Comment: If you don't know you can pass parameters to a function... better get a book to learn C# and OOP, not trying to offend, but you lack the basic knowledge to program using objects.

Comment: Wasn't aware that I can have classes without constructors & can simply use static methods. You really aren't being helpful by insulting FYI

Comment: @maccartm, If you find insulting comments - flagging offensive/too chatty is good option. So far I don't see any offensive comments (probably already deleted). Gusman's recommendation to read on basics of language before asking questions is very valid, especially if you plan to keep that SO account for a while (it is somewhat expected that <50 points account holders don't read at all).

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov the part that I found offensive was Gusman making a *blatantly untrue* statement (regarding passing parameters to a function) and saying I need to read up due to this fallacy. My own example shows me "passing parameters to a function" which he claims I don't know how to do. I read this as "you're an idiot" because I asked for help. I've had some extensive experience programming using objects, I'm simply new to C# and have been "winging it" based on my knowledge of Python/Java/C. Thank you for the advice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to have some logic that you can run from anywhere in your application.  For that, you'd use a static method.

A Static method requires no instance to run.

Since all `BClass` does is contain a static method, you might as well make `BClass` static too.  A static class is a class that cannot be instantiated.  It only exists to contain static methods.

```
public static class BClass
{
    public static void DoStuff(int[] x)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            x[i] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

And when you want to use this logic, you simply do this

```
BClass.DoStuff(myArray);
```

Comment: As noted in the comments this is exactly what I was looking for; thank you for the well-structured answer with an explanation